NoClassDefFoundError sun/misc/ServiceConfigurationError in my javafx project with gmail api
I have a javafx project and i want to send emails with it to users.
I have done everything from google's guide https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java but when i run it it says
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/ServiceConfigurationError
at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:110)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth@1.34.1/com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver.getRedirectUri(LocalServerReceiver.java:127)
at com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth@1.34.1/com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.authorize(AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.java:109)
at com.omega.omegapeoject1/com.omega.omegapeoject1.models.Gmailer.getCredentials(Gmailer.java:61)
at com.omega.omegapeoject1/com.omega.omegapeoject1.models.Gmailer.\<init\>(Gmailer.java:38)
at com.omega.omegapeoject1/com.omega.omegapeoject1.models.Gmailer.getInstance(Gmailer.java:44)
at com.omega.omegapeoject1/com.omega.omegapeoject1.Main1.main(Main1.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.ServiceConfigurationError
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
7 more

The error occured in this function
specific in the authorize("user");
    private Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport httpTransport, GsonFactory jsonFactory) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = Gmailer.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret_311696558202-3pehuqquhmnes5f96tp25kqlnt97l71e.apps.googleusercontent.com.json");
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: /client_secret_311696558202-e6fdr29it2msssjbtp52ol2ggard2jr8.apps.googleusercontent.com.json");
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(jsonFactory, new InputStreamReader(in));

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, Set.of(GMAIL_SEND))
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(Paths.get("tokens").toFile()))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();

        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

pls help me :(
I use IntelliJ 2024 on windows 11 and java jdk 21
this is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.omega</groupId>
    <artifactId>OmegaPeoject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>OmegaPeoject1</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.10.0</junit.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>1.34.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev20220404-2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.net.httpserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>http</artifactId>
            <version>20070405</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.net.httpserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>http</artifactId>
            <version>20070405</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.11.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.omega.omegapeoject1/com.omega.omegapeoject1.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

and module-info if it helps
module com.omega.omegapeoject1 {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.sql;
    requires javafx.web;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires google.api.client;
    requires com.google.api.client;
    requires com.google.api.client.json.gson;
    requires com.google.api.services.gmail;
    requires com.google.api.client.auth;
    requires com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth;
    requires com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth;
    requires org.apache.commons.codec;
    requires jdk.unsupported;
    requires mail;


    opens com.omega.omegapeoject1 to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.omega.omegapeoject1;
    exports com.omega.omegapeoject1.Controllers;
    opens com.omega.omegapeoject1.Controllers to javafx.fxml;
    opens com.omega.omegapeoject1.models to javafx.base;
    opens com.omega.omegapeoject1.models.database to javafx.base;}

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Why have you got a mixture of Gradle and Maven? Their quickstart is just Gradle by the looks

My recommendation: 1.  Delete the module info to make the project non modular 2. Use a jdk that includes JavaFX from Azul or BellSoft.  3. Don’t include JavaFX dependencies in your project. 4. Try again.
